# Why symfony doctrine findall() return id NULL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i have service class:

```
  <?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Service
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ServiceRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"newsletter" = "Newsletter", "email" = "Email", "service" = "Service"})
 * 
 */
class Service
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="serviceTitle", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $serviceTitle;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set serviceTitle
     *
     * @param string $serviceTitle
     *
     * @return Service
     */
    public function setServiceTitle($serviceTitle)
    {
        $this->serviceTitle = $serviceTitle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get serviceTitle
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getServiceTitle()
    {
        return $this->serviceTitle;
    }


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Service", inversedBy="children")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Service", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;
    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Set parent
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Service $parent
     *
     * @return Service
     */
    public function setParent(\AppBundle\Entity\Service $parent = null)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get parent
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Service
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    /**
     * Add child
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Service $child
     *
     * @return Service
     */
    public function addChild(\AppBundle\Entity\Service $child)
    {
        $this->children[] = $child;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove child
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Service $child
     */
    public function removeChild(\AppBundle\Entity\Service $child)
    {
        $this->children->removeElement($child);
    }

    /**
     * Get children
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->children;
    }
}
```

and email class which extends servic class:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Email
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\EmailRepository")
 */
class Email extends Service
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="emailAddress", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $emailAddress;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set emailAddress
     *
     * @param string $emailAddress
     *
     * @return Email
     */
    public function setEmailAddress($emailAddress)
    {
        $this->emailAddress = $emailAddress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get emailAddress
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailAddress()
    {
        return $this->emailAddress;
    }
}
```

i generate crud for email and my email controller index action showing list of emails, it have doctrine findall() function but problem is , this findall function return entity with ID->NULL

can any one tell me why its return null???

```
 public function indexAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Email')->findAll();


    var_dump($entities);
    exit();
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Email:index.html.twig', array(
        'entities' => $entities,
    ));
}
```

[image]

Comment: why do you define id again in your extended class? id should be inherited from Service, right?

Comment: ahh, while creating entity ID automatically created, but i forgot to remove after that,

now i removed and its working fine, and now ID is coming with FindAll()

Thanks man

Comment: Thanks - you should accept @Wilt s answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33229741/symfony-catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-appbundle-entity-email-could-not

can you please answer this one, answer  end of the page, last comment.

Answer (score 2):

You have a base class `Service` and extend this class in your `Email` class. You also redefine the `id` column there. This is not allowed.

Your problem probably relates to this. Check [the Doctrine2 documentation on attribute override](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#attribute-override) for more information.

I suggest you remove the id column totally from your `Email` entity:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Email
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\EmailRepository")
 */
class Email extends Service
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="emailAddress", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $emailAddress;

    /**
     * Set emailAddress
     *
     * @param string $emailAddress
     *
     * @return Email
     */
    public function setEmailAddress($emailAddress)
    {
        $this->emailAddress = $emailAddress;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get emailAddress
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmailAddress()
    {
        return $this->emailAddress;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use a [mapped superclass](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) for class Service.
Its fields will be mapped, but the only entity appearing in the database will be Email.

```
<?php
/** @MappedSuperclass */
class Service
{
    /** @Column(type="string") */
    protected $serviceTitle;

    // ... more fields and methods
}

/** @Entity */
class Email extends Service
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;
    /** @Column(type="string") */
    private $emailAddress;

    // ... more fields and methods
}
```

Comment: There was a typo in the answer, but it's been fixed and I think it's valid now.